# Issue trying to render animation through command line

Tags: rendering, command-line

Trying to render an animation for class through command line. I did the following:

1. `cd /Applications/Blender.app`
2. `blender -b /Users/name/Downloads/SPRING 2022/INFOTC2620/mod5/nameAssignment05/nameAssignment05.blend -a`

but all I'm getting is command not found. How do i fix this?

Comment: I'm not certain, because it's macos(I think), but the command should be ./blender ..., instead of blender

Comment: There's a whole directory hierarchy under the Blender.app directory. Try `find /Applications/Blender.app -name blender` to see where the executable is.

Answer (score 0):

if you are in your applications directory, type this:

```
cd Blender.app/Contents/MacOS
```

then you can start running Blender like this:

```
./Blender -b /Users/name/Downloads/SPRING 2022/INFOTC2620/mod5/nameAssignment05/nameAssignment05.blend -a
```